# How do I set up my application/EC2 instance so that I don't have to put the port number at the end of the IP?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to point my domain to my EC2 instance but it isn't working because my EC2 needs the port (:3000) at the end of the IP in order to be resolved.  I'm having a really difficult time finding information on this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can install pm2 and start your application on port 80. `sudo npm install pm2 -g` then `Open up your apps index.js file and change port 5000 to port 80` and finally `pm2 start index.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up an internet facing load balancer to redirect the port 80 from public access to your ec2 instance with any port.

> internet users -> hit your new created load balancer with port 80 or 443 -> set redirection rules to backend (ec2:port)

There are several types of aws loadbalancer, you can start with [Elastic load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)

if you want to save the cost, you can install `nginx` or `haproxy` on your ec2 instances to expose the port 80 directly.

Answer (score 1):

Using this

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000

Will do the magic for you

Edit: Remember that this is not the recommended way if you are deploying your website and using certbot to enable ssl. Certbot need to direct connect port 80 to enable your ssl.

The better approach to do this is using some kind of server ( nginx, apache) install directly and started in your vps. Go to the config path and edit the configuration mapping in your vps server.

For example with nginx, vim etc/nginx/site-available/default and config mapping:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    
    # Map any https://your-domain-here.com to http://localhost:3000 ( running port in your server )
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    }
}
```